# How to update class field

Tags: java

I didn't know how to explain in the title, so here it is.

In class `Passenger` i have field `balance`, getters and setters ofc.

In another class I have some method, in that method I have some computation and it looks like this:

```
System.out.println("New balance of: " + selectedPassenger.getFirstName() + " is: " + (selectedPassenger.getBalance() - discountEconomyClass()));
```

As you can see I take the `balance` field, that is field from `Passenger` class, then I subtract that field from some method, it doesn't matter.

Then I display the list but in that list the value of the balance has not changed.

```
  @Override
public void showPassengerList(ArrayList<Passenger> passengersList) {
    System.out.println("---Passengers list--");
    for (Passenger tempPassenger : passengersList) {
        System.out.println(tempPassenger);
    }
}
```

Before executing that method where I subtract balance, balance is:

`balance=300.0` after I run program and that method is executed `balance` is the same on the list. How to update balance?

I tried with this but don't know how exactly:

```
System.out.println("New balance is: " + selectedPassenger.setBalance());
```

Comment: Try this: `selectedPassenger.getBalance() -= discountEconomyClass()` in your calculations.

Comment: You haven’t updated the value on the passenger (passenger.setBalance), you’ve just done a sum using that value. `passenger.setBalance(passenger.getBalance() - discountEconomyClass());` would perform the update.

Comment: Should you do `System.out.println("New balance is: " + selectedPassenger.setBalance(selectedPassenger.getBalance() - discountEconomyClass()));`?

Comment: Updating the balance and printing it are two totally unrelated things. First, calculate the new balance and set it (`selectedPassenger.setBalance(electedPassenger.getBalance() - discountEconomyClass())`) and afterwards print the updated balance directly (`System.out.println("New balance of: " + selectedPassenger.getFirstName() + " is: " + selectedPassenger.getBalance());`).

Comment: Thank you guys also, you helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you're only printing out the new balance.  You aren't setting the balance to the new value.  Try something like this:

```
selectedPassenger.setBalance(selectedPassenger.getBalance() - discountEconomyClass());
```